# AppCompat buttons: background always white for API < 21

Tags: android, button, android-appcompat

I use Material designs Theme in my app and have no problems with API more and equal 21.
But with API < 21 I have some critical issues, which can't resolve.

For API < 21 I use AppCompat Theme to get Material Theme effect.

And lets look at the Button example:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonShare"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:src="@drawable/share"       
        android:theme="@style/StandartButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"  
        />
```

And style.xml file:

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/StandartButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="StandartButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">   
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/blue</item>               
    </style>
```

As a result:

[image]

I didn't add styles-v21 with the correct screenshot because it works correct with almost the same code.

So any ideas how to solve the issue with the old API vers?

Comment: add `<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/blue</item>`

Comment: android:colorButtonNormal requires API level 21 (current min is 16)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, not sure understand what do mean. Instead of ImageButton I should use Button? Also, dont use style, only theme?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the right solution playing with styles (probably it's AppCompat bug), that's why found a workaround fix.

Add `layout-v21` folder with the button refers to the style with Material Theme.
And set `background` in current `layout` folder.

Note, that it can be only a temporary fix.